# use and import an old script in new vue app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, markerclusterer

Iam rebuilding an app that is built in angularjs that was created 10 years ago.
Iam rebuilding it with vue.js

The old app uses a downloaded script called 'MarkerClustererPlus' se complete script further down.(removed some code from the script because it passed the charecter limit)

I copied the script into my app and imported it like this since i can only use javascript ES5

```
 const MarkerClusterer = require('../libs/markerclusterer');
```

I try to create a instance of it like this:

```
                let mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, mapMarkers, {
                    maxZoom: 15,
                    gridSize: 50,
                    styles: clusterStyles
                });
```

But i get this error msg

```
 TypeError: MarkerClusterer is not a constructor
```

How do i import this old script propably into my vue app? The very same code works in the old angularjs app

This is the script

```
/*jslint browser: true, confusion: true, sloppy: true, vars: true, nomen: false, plusplus: false, indent: 2 */
/*global window,google */

/**
 * @name MarkerClustererPlus for Google Maps V3
 * @version 2.0.1 [July 27, 2011]
 * @author Gary Little
 * @fileoverview
 * The library creates and manages per-zoom-level clusters for large amounts of markers.
 * <p>
 * This is an enhanced V3 implementation of the
 * <a href="http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/"
 * >V2 MarkerClusterer</a> by Xiaoxi Wu. It is based on the
 * <a href="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/"
 * >V3 MarkerClusterer</a> port by Luke Mahe. MarkerClustererPlus was created by Gary Little.
 * <p>
 * v2.0 release: MarkerClustererPlus v2.0 is backward compatible with MarkerClusterer v1.0. It
 *  adds support for the <code>ignoreHidden</code>, <code>title</code>, <code>printable</code>,
 *  <code>batchSizeIE</code>, and <code>calculator</code> properties as well as support for
 *  four more events. It also allows greater control over the styling of the text that appears
 *  on the cluster marker. The documentation has been significantly improved and the overall
 *  code has been simplified and polished. Very large numbers of markers can now be managed
 *  without causing Javascript timeout errors on Internet Explorer. Note that the name of the
 *  <code>clusterclick</code> event has been deprecated. The new name is <code>click</code>,
 *  so please change your application code now.
 */

/**
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


/**
 * @name ClusterIconStyle
 * @class This class represents the object for values in the <code>styles</code> array passed
 *  to the {@link MarkerClusterer} constructor. The element in this array that is used to
 *  style the cluster icon is determined by calling the <code>calculator</code> function.
 *
 * @property {string} url The URL of the cluster icon image file. Required.
 * @property {number} height The height (in pixels) of the cluster icon. Required.
 * @property {number} width The width (in pixels) of the cluster icon. Required.
 * @property {Array} [anchor] The anchor position (in pixels) of the label text to be shown on
 *  the cluster icon, relative to the top left corner of the icon.
 *  The format is <code>[yoffset, xoffset]</code>. The <code>yoffset</code> must be positive
 *  and less than <code>height</code> and the <code>xoffset</code> must be positive and less
 *  than <code>width</code>. The default is to anchor the label text so that it is centered
 *  on the icon.
 * @property {string} [textColor="black"] The color of the label text shown on the
 *  cluster icon.
 * @property {number} [textSize=11] The size (in pixels) of the label text shown on the
 *  cluster icon.
 * @property {number} [textDecoration="none"] The value of the CSS <code>text-decoration</code>
 *  property for the label text shown on the cluster icon.
 * @property {number} [fontWeight="bold"] The value of the CSS <code>font-weight</code>
 *  property for the label text shown on the cluster icon.
 * @property {number} [fontStyle="normal"] The value of the CSS <code>font-style</code>
 *  property for the label text shown on the cluster icon.
 * @property {number} [fontFamily="Arial,sans-serif"] The value of the CSS <code>font-family</code>
 *  property for the label text shown on the cluster icon.
 * @property {string} [backgroundPosition="0 0"] The position of the cluster icon image
 *  within the image defined by <code>url</code>. The format is <code>"xpos ypos"</code>
 *  (the same format as for the CSS <code>background-position</code> property). You must set
 *  this property appropriately when the image defined by <code>url</code> represents a sprite
 *  containing multiple images.
 */
/**
 * @name ClusterIconInfo
 * @class This class is an object containing general information about a cluster icon. This is
 *  the object that a <code>calculator</code> function returns.
 *
 * @property {string} text The text of the label to be shown on the cluster icon.
 * @property {number} index The index plus 1 of the element in the <code>styles</code>
 *  array to be used to style the cluster icon.
 */
/**
 * A cluster icon.
 *
 * @constructor
 * @extends google.maps.OverlayView
 * @param {Cluster} cluster The cluster with which the icon is to be associated.
 * @param {Array} [styles] An array of {@link ClusterIconStyle} defining the cluster icons
 *  to use for various cluster sizes.
 * @private
 */
function ClusterIcon(cluster, styles) {
  cluster.getMarkerClusterer().extend(ClusterIcon, google.maps.OverlayView);

  this.cluster_ = cluster;
  this.styles_ = styles;
  this.center_ = null;
  this.div_ = null;
  this.sums_ = null;
  this.visible_ = false;

  this.setMap(cluster.getMap()); // Note: this causes onAdd to be called
}





/**
 * Implementation of the onAdd interface method.
 * @ignore
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.onAdd = function () {
  var cMarkerClusterer = this;

  this.activeMap_ = this.getMap();
  this.ready_ = true;

  this.repaint();

  // Add the map event listeners
  this.listeners_ = [
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.getMap(), "zoom_changed", function () {
      cMarkerClusterer.resetViewport_(false);
    }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.getMap(), "idle", function () {
      cMarkerClusterer.redraw_();
    })
  ];
};


/**
 * Implementation of the onRemove interface method.
 * Removes map event listeners and all cluster icons from the DOM.
 * All managed markers are also put back on the map.
 * @ignore
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.onRemove = function () {
  var i;

  // Put all the managed markers back on the map:
  for (i = 0; i < this.markers_.length; i++) {
    this.markers_[i].setMap(this.activeMap_);
  }

  // Remove all clusters:
  for (i = 0; i < this.clusters_.length; i++) {
    this.clusters_[i].remove();
  }
  this.clusters_ = [];

  // Remove map event listeners:
  for (i = 0; i < this.listeners_.length; i++) {
    google.maps.event.removeListener(this.listeners_[i]);
  }
  this.listeners_ = [];

  this.activeMap_ = null;
  this.ready_ = false;
};


/**
 * Implementation of the draw interface method.
 * @ignore
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.draw = function () {};


/**
 * Sets up the styles object.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setupStyles_ = function () {
  var i, size;
  if (this.styles_.length > 0) {
    return;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < this.imageSizes_.length; i++) {
    size = this.imageSizes_[i];
    this.styles_.push({
      url: this.imagePath_ + (i + 1) + "." + this.imageExtension_,
      height: size,
      width: size
    });
  }
};


/**
 *  Fits the map to the bounds of the markers managed by the clusterer.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.fitMapToMarkers = function () {
  var i;
  var markers = this.getMarkers();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }

  this.getMap().fitBounds(bounds);
};


/**
 * Returns the value of the <code>gridSize</code> property.
 *
 * @return {number} The grid size.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getGridSize = function () {
  return this.gridSize_;
};


/**
 * Sets the value of the <code>gridSize</code> property.
 *
 * @param {number} gridSize The grid size.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setGridSize = function (gridSize) {
  this.gridSize_ = gridSize;
};


/**
 * Returns the value of the <code>minimumClusterSize</code> property.
 *
 * @return {number} The minimum cluster size.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getMinimumClusterSize = function () {
  return this.minClusterSize_;
};

/**
 * Sets the value of the <code>minimumClusterSize</code> property.
 *
 * @param {number} minimumClusterSize The minimum cluster size.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setMinimumClusterSize = function (minimumClusterSize) {
  this.minClusterSize_ = minimumClusterSize;
};


/**
 *  Returns the value of the <code>maxZoom</code> property.
 *
 *  @return {number} The maximum zoom level.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getMaxZoom = function () {
  return this.maxZoom_ || this.getMap().mapTypes[this.getMap().getMapTypeId()].maxZoom;
};


/**
 *  Sets the value of the <code>maxZoom</code> property.
 *
 *  @param {number} maxZoom The maximum zoom level.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setMaxZoom = function (maxZoom) {
  this.maxZoom_ = maxZoom;
};


/**
 *  Returns the value of the <code>styles</code> property.
 *
 *  @return {Array} The array of styles defining the cluster markers to be used.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getStyles = function () {
  return this.styles_;
};


/**
 *  Sets the value of the <code>styles</code> property.
 *
 *  @param {Array.<ClusterIconStyle>} styles The array of styles to use.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setStyles = function (styles) {
  this.styles_ = styles;
};


/**
 * Returns the value of the <code>title</code> property.
 *
 * @return {string} The content of the title text.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getTitle = function () {
  return this.title_;
};


/**
 *  Sets the value of the <code>title</code> property.
 *
 *  @param {string} title The value of the title property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setTitle = function (title) {
  this.title_ = title;
};


/**
 * Returns the value of the <code>zoomOnClick</code> property.
 *
 * @return {boolean} True if zoomOnClick property is set.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getZoomOnClick = function () {
  return this.zoomOnClick_;
};


/**
 *  Sets the value of the <code>zoomOnClick</code> property.
 *
 *  @param {boolean} zoomOnClick The value of the zoomOnClick property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setZoomOnClick = function (zoomOnClick) {
  this.zoomOnClick_ = zoomOnClick;
};


/**
 * Returns the value of the <code>averageCenter</code> property.
 *
 * @return {boolean} True if averageCenter property is set.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getAverageCenter = function () {
  return this.averageCenter_;
};


/**
 *  Sets the value of the <code>averageCenter</code> property.
 *
 *  @param {boolean} averageCenter The value of the averageCenter property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setAverageCenter = function (averageCenter) {
  this.averageCenter_ = averageCenter;
};


/**
 * Returns the value of the <code>ignoreHidden</code> property.
 *
 * @return {boolean} True if ignoreHidden property is set.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getIgnoreHidden = function () {
  return this.ignoreHidden_;
};


/**
 *  Sets the value of the <code>ignoreHidden</code> property.
 *
 *  @param {boolean} ignoreHidden The value of the ignoreHidden property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setIgnoreHidden = function (ignoreHidden) {
  this.ignoreHidden_ = ignoreHidden;
};


/**
 * Returns the value of the <code>imageExtension</code> property.
 *
 * @return {string} The value of the imageExtension property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getImageExtension = function () {
  return this.imageExtension_;
};


/**
 *  Sets the value of the <code>imageExtension</code> property.
 *
 *  @param {string} imageExtension The value of the imageExtension property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setImageExtension = function (imageExtension) {
  this.imageExtension_ = imageExtension;
};


/**
 * Returns the value of the <code>imagePath</code> property.
 *
 * @return {string} The value of the imagePath property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getImagePath = function () {
  return this.imagePath_;
};


/**
 *  Sets the value of the <code>imagePath</code> property.
 *
 *  @param {string} imagePath The value of the imagePath property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setImagePath = function (imagePath) {
  this.imagePath_ = imagePath;
};


/**
 * Returns the value of the <code>imageSizes</code> property.
 *
 * @return {Array} The value of the imageSizes property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getImageSizes = function () {
  return this.imageSizes_;
};


/**
 *  Sets the value of the <code>imageSizes</code> property.
 *
 *  @param {Array} imageSizes The value of the imageSizes property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setImageSizes = function (imageSizes) {
  this.imageSizes_ = imageSizes;
};


/**
 * Returns the value of the <code>calculator</code> property.
 *
 * @return {function} the value of the calculator property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getCalculator = function () {
  return this.calculator_;
};


/**
 * Sets the value of the <code>calculator</code> property.
 *
 * @param {function(Array.<google.maps.Marker>, number)} calculator The value
 *  of the calculator property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setCalculator = function (calculator) {
  this.calculator_ = calculator;
};


/**
 * Returns the value of the <code>printable</code> property.
 *
 * @return {boolean} the value of the printable property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getPrintable = function () {
  return this.printable_;
};


/**
 * Sets the value of the <code>printable</code> property.
 *
 *  @param {boolean} printable The value of the printable property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setPrintable = function (printable) {
  this.printable_ = printable;
};


/**
 * Returns the value of the <code>batchSizeIE</code> property.
 *
 * @return {number} the value of the batchSizeIE property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getBatchSizeIE = function () {
  return this.batchSizeIE_;
};


/**
 * Sets the value of the <code>batchSizeIE</code> property.
 *
 *  @param {number} batchSizeIE The value of the batchSizeIE property.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setBatchSizeIE = function (batchSizeIE) {
  this.batchSizeIE_ = batchSizeIE;
};


/**
 *  Returns the array of markers managed by the clusterer.
 *
 *  @return {Array} The array of markers managed by the clusterer.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getMarkers = function () {
  return this.markers_;
};


/**
 *  Returns the number of markers managed by the clusterer.
 *
 *  @return {number} The number of markers.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getTotalMarkers = function () {
  return this.markers_.length;
};


/**
 * Returns the number of clusters formed by the clusterer.
 *
 * @return {number} The number of clusters formed by the clusterer.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.getTotalClusters = function () {
  return this.clusters_.length;
};


/**
 * Adds a marker to the clusterer. The clusters are redrawn unless
 *  <code>opt_nodraw</code> is set to <code>true</code>.
 *
 * @param {google.maps.Marker} marker The marker to add.
 * @param {boolean} [opt_nodraw] Set to <code>true</code> to prevent redrawing.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.addMarker = function (marker, opt_nodraw) {
  this.pushMarkerTo_(marker);
  if (!opt_nodraw) {
    this.redraw_();
  }
};


/**
 * Adds an array of markers to the clusterer. The clusters are redrawn unless
 *  <code>opt_nodraw</code> is set to <code>true</code>.
 *
 * @param {Array.<google.maps.Marker>} markers The markers to add.
 * @param {boolean} [opt_nodraw] Set to <code>true</code> to prevent redrawing.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.addMarkers = function (markers, opt_nodraw) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    this.pushMarkerTo_(markers[i]);
  }
  if (!opt_nodraw) {
    this.redraw_();
  }
};


/**
 * Pushes a marker to the clusterer.
 *
 * @param {google.maps.Marker} marker The marker to add.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.pushMarkerTo_ = function (marker) {
  // If the marker is draggable add a listener so we can update the clusters on the dragend:
  if (marker.getDraggable()) {
    var cMarkerClusterer = this;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
      if (cMarkerClusterer.ready_) {
        this.isAdded = false;
        cMarkerClusterer.repaint();
      }
    });
  }
  marker.isAdded = false;
  this.markers_.push(marker);
};


/**
 * Removes a marker from the cluster.  The clusters are redrawn unless
 *  <code>opt_nodraw</code> is set to <code>true</code>. Returns <code>true</code> if the
 *  marker was removed from the clusterer.
 *
 * @param {google.maps.Marker} marker The marker to remove.
 * @param {boolean} [opt_nodraw] Set to <code>true</code> to prevent redrawing.
 * @return {boolean} True if the marker was removed from the clusterer.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.removeMarker = function (marker, opt_nodraw) {
  var removed = this.removeMarker_(marker);

  if (!opt_nodraw && removed) {
    this.repaint();
  }

  return removed;
};


/**
 * Removes an array of markers from the cluster. The clusters are redrawn unless
 *  <code>opt_nodraw</code> is set to <code>true</code>. Returns <code>true</code> if markers
 *  were removed from the clusterer.
 *
 * @param {Array.<google.maps.Marker>} markers The markers to remove.
 * @param {boolean} [opt_nodraw] Set to <code>true</code> to prevent redrawing.
 * @return {boolean} True if markers were removed from the clusterer.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.removeMarkers = function (markers, opt_nodraw) {
  var i, r;
  var removed = false;

  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    r = this.removeMarker_(markers[i]);
    removed = removed || r;
  }

  if (!opt_nodraw && removed) {
    this.repaint();
  }

  return removed;
};


/**
 * Removes a marker and returns true if removed, false if not.
 *
 * @param {google.maps.Marker} marker The marker to remove
 * @return {boolean} Whether the marker was removed or not
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.removeMarker_ = function (marker) {
  var i;
  var index = -1;
  if (this.markers_.indexOf) {
    index = this.markers_.indexOf(marker);
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < this.markers_.length; i++) {
      if (marker === this.markers_[i]) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (index === -1) {
    // Marker is not in our list of markers, so do nothing:
    return false;
  }

  marker.setMap(null);
  this.markers_.splice(index, 1); // Remove the marker from the list of managed markers
  return true;
};


/**
 * Removes all clusters and markers from the map and also removes all markers
 *  managed by the clusterer.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.clearMarkers = function () {
  this.resetViewport_(true);
  this.markers_ = [];
};


/**
 * Recalculates and redraws all the marker clusters from scratch.
 *  Call this after changing any properties.
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.repaint = function () {
  var oldClusters = this.clusters_.slice();
  this.clusters_ = [];
  this.resetViewport_(false);
  this.redraw_();

  // Remove the old clusters.
  // Do it in a timeout to prevent blinking effect.
  setTimeout(function () {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < oldClusters.length; i++) {
      oldClusters[i].remove();
    }
  }, 0);
};
```

Comment: `import { MarkerClusterer } from '../libs/markerclusterer'` inside the script of vue component.

Comment: using es5. How would i do that using es5? @Nitheesh

Comment: Looks like this https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclustererplus   https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclustererplus/blob/main/src/markerclusterer.ts

Comment: You shouldn't import a script that wasn't written as a module, a lot of times it will fail because it relies on being evaluated in a global scope. If you have control over it, consider fixing it to fit modular environment. "I copied the script into my app and imported it like this since i can only use javascript ES5" - why is there such requirement? There's no `require` in vanilla JS. And in compiled app you're not limited to es5. If you want to write in vanilla es5, there's absolutely no difference from angularjs, it will be the same outdated code in Vue. Just load it with `<script>`